# Selection Error

Tags: 3d-view, selection-tools, error

Ever since 2.8 was officially released, ive had a problem whenever i select something that isnt a mesh object (cameras, bones, curves, metaballs, text, etc) i get an error message that pops up. as far as i know, its not preventing me from doing anything, but it does get annoying to have to mouse away and back again every time i want to select something[image]

I have no idea what any of this is telling me besides the file location, and nothing has changed after i deleted and reinstalled blender

does anyone know a fix or even just any way to disable the message from popping up every time?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind it turns out right mouse button was somehow bound to something else, and apparently those bindings carry over even after you reinstall blender. might as well keep this post up in case someone else has an issue like this

Comment: For 2.81 I finally gave up my old settings with right click select... takes some getting used to, after the initial right click select took some time to get used to, lol.